# While automating a mainframe application with Jagacy jar, getting error message stating "KDB16104I Application has not been defined to CICS"

Tags: java, automation, mainframe

I am new to mainframe automation and is trying to automate the application using Jagacy jar and java. At one particular screen I have to input a number ranging from 0 to 9, henceforth I am using writePosition function provided by jagacy to input value on screen. But the problem is, it takes only the String value as parameter.
When I tried to input number 6 as string it gave an error message stating `KDB16104I Application has not been defined to CICS`.

I am unaware of what CICS is and nothing much is available on google about this error. Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
public void writePosition(final int i, final int j, final String s) 
throws JagacyException {
    if (i < 0 || i >= this.getHeight()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid row: " + i);
    }
    if (j < 0 || j >= this.getWidth()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column: " + j);
    }
    this.writeCursor(i, j);
    this.writeString(s);
}
```

`Error message: "KDB16104I Application has not been defined to CICS"`

Comment: Is CICS a group at your company?  My guess is that the mainframe will only run applications that it 'knows' about, meaning that some system admin has allowed that application to run.  I would recommend that you ask around and see what your company's policies are for running applications on the mainframe.

Comment: CICS is an application container similar to WebSphere Application Server or Apache Tomcat.  It is not a small topic.  Someone on the mainframe security team must authorize an ID to sign on to CICS and to execute the particular application (what CICS calls a transaction) that displays the screen to which you refer.

Comment: The issue here is , the above function is working on one machine and is not working on other.To add to this it is not user specific issue as my ID worked on the machine where the code is working fine.On my machine also the code worked for few screens(login and selection of option)but at that particular screen where an integer value is required ,it says application is not  registered to CICS.

Answer (score 1):

You're either not driving the target application environment correctly, or the target application environment is unwilling to be driven in the way you're trying to drive it. It's just that simple. And conceptually the solution is simple too: go through standard troubleshooting procedures when you think you're providing correct input and not getting the response you expect.

You can safely assume that the communication path is working at a basic level. That error message is coming back from your mainframe, and it's simply saying, in effect, "I'm not going to do what you're asking." I would now try logging on (using a user-operated terminal emulator) with exactly the same connection details and credentials (user ID, password), then see if that option 6 works. If it doesn't, then it isn't going to work from terminal automation either. If it does work, then try another number in that field to see if it also works. If that other number works -- let's suppose it's the number 3 -- then try 3 in your automation. If 3 doesn't work in your automation, then something is wrong in your Jagacy automation, such as a codepage setting, PS position (row, column -- typically PS position values will start from 1, not from 0), 3270 model type (standard models are 2 through 5, and that'll influence how many columns and rows the mainframe will display), possibly whether you have TN3270E configured instead of TN3270 (the "E" is almost always what you want), or something else. You might also want to try inserting some wait time (a pause) before that number 6 is entered, and then you have some more work to do to cure that problem if that's the problem.

I'm not enthusiastic about terminal-driven automation, by the way. Yes, it's a long practiced art, but it's too often practiced in my view. What are you trying to accomplish? Since this is CICS you're interacting with (or trying to), CICS itself provides so many, many other interaction choices beyond terminal-based interactions.